# How to remove original element after it was cloned?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <p class="test1">test 1</p>
    <p class="test2">test 2</p>
    <p class="test3">test 3</p>
    <p class="test4">test 4</p>
</div>

<div class="clickdiv">click</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.clickdiv').on('click', function(){
    $('.test1').clone().appendTo('#test');
}
```

This will result one more `<p>` with `class = "test1"`. Now how can I remove the original one that is first one?

Comment: `$('.test1').appendTo('#test');` no need to clone

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know why you can't just append the element to the parent, instead of cloning it then removing it.

Anyway

```
$('.test1').remove().clone().appendTo('#test');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xhDQy/)

If you want to copy the data and handlers associated with `test1` to the clone then @ra_htial with a minor change have to be used

```
$('.clickdiv').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $('.test1');
    $el.clone(true).appendTo('#test');
    $el.remove();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aZTUW/)

Comment: when you click again this will not function. that is the cloned element doesn't have class?

Comment: @C-Link because `.test1` is already at the bottom of the parent so append does not do anything

Comment: You can always use `end()`. It's pretty handy, but often not used. But you should definitely go with `A. Wolff's` comment

Comment: I tried both method but not what my slider is doing can you post about end() also.

Comment: Thanks, but just don't understand how clone() works AFTER remove(), I thought it would not find anything to clone since, obviously, it has been removed?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.clickdiv').on('click', function(){
    var test1 =$('.test1');
    test1.clone().appendTo('#test');
    test1.remove();
}
```

Comment: test1 is already a jQuery object, so you don't need to pass it to $() again

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the element because `appendTo` will copy and "remove" it.

You can simply do :

```
$('.test1').appendTo('#test');
```